# Very poor performance on Chrome using CreateJS

Tags: google-chrome, canvas, html5-canvas, easeljs, createjs

I have a game I am developing for a client. Its not a particularly intensive game graphically but it does have quite a few different animations and a large number of textures. It seems that there is a threshold for the number of different spritesheet based animations that I have have in Chrome. When I go beyond that point (about 5 different animations) the FPS tanks to about 5FPS.

The weird thing is the game runs at a solid 60FPS all the time in Firefox with no problems.

It appears that it something to do with the way Chrome does hardware acceleration of the 2D canvas.

Note this video of the game, the game runs at a silky smooth 60FPS (see bottom right for FPS counter) when the game is smaller than about 220px high, but as soon as its even a little higher than that then it runs at 5-10FPS:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3VWo6eQmy1g&feature=youtu.be

I think its got to be related to this issue:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=170021

It says fixed but I dont think it is.

Does anyone have any more info on this?!

Cheers!

Comment: Its definately something to do with the number of animated spritesheets on the screen as this video shows: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ske-Q_4v4c0&feature=youtu.be As soon as you have more than 5 on the screen everything slows down.

Comment: I have now found the solution to this issue. I needed to split the spritesheets up into separate frames at load time, then create my own sprite rendering system. Ill write a fuller answer later.

Comment: do you have a fuller answer?